# How to add a primary key to a mysql table without a primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

I need to add a primary key to a table in Mysql with existing data.

STATES:

```
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| country_code | varchar(2)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state_code   | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state_name   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have created a States2 table which is empty and contains a primary key in it.

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| country_code | varchar(2)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state_code   | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state_name   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What I want to do now is grab the data from States and copy it to States2 and at the same time add the Autoincrement primary key.

This is what I have tried:

```
mysql> insert into states2 select NULL,states.* FROM states;
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'id' cannot be null
```

What is the correct way to copy this and at the same time insert the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explictly assigning a `null`  value to a primary key column, which MySQL won't allow (a primary key cannot be `null`).

Just leave apart the primary key column from the `insert` statement so the auto-increment can happen:

```
insert into states2 (country_code, state_code, state_name) 
select country_code, state_code, state_name FROM states;
```